# Wanting to deference my array contents to zero. Only first number in array changes to zero

Tags: c

I am new to stackoverflow and C and I have a question. I am required to write a program that will iterate through an array, and then dereference the contents to zero. For some reason, my "zero_out_array" will only change the first number in my array to zero, and not the rest. Here is my code, any help is appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_array(int* p_array, int num_elements)
{
    printf("print_array called:\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < num_elements; i++)
    {
        printf("%d \n", p_array[i]);
    }
}

void zero_out_array(int* p_array, int num_elements)
{
    printf("zero_out_array called:\n");

    *p_array = 0;

    for (int j = 0; j < num_elements; j++)
    {
        printf("%d \n", p_array[j]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int main_array[] = { 15, 24, 33, 42, 51 };

    print_array(main_array, 5);

    zero_out_array(main_array, 5);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `*p_array = 0;` refers only to the first element of the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please consider the code modified as below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_array(int* p_array, int num_elements)
{
    printf("print_array called:\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < num_elements; i++)
    {
        printf("%d \n", p_array[i]);
    }
}

void zero_out_array(int* p_array, int num_elements)
{
    printf("zero_out_array called:\n");

    *p_array = 0;

    for(int j = 0; j < num_elements; j++)
        *(p_array+j)=0;

    for (int j = 0; j < num_elements; j++)
    {
        printf("%d \n", p_array[j]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int main_array[] = { 15, 24, 33, 42, 51 };

    print_array(main_array, 5);

    zero_out_array(main_array, 5);

    return 0;
}
```

In the above code, I have added the extra for loop:

```
for(int j = 0; j < num_elements; j++)
        *(p_array+j)=0;
```

`*p_array` points only to the first element of the array, so I have used a for loop to change all the elements.  By doing `*(p_array+j)=0`, I am iteratively visiting all the array elements and making them 0.

Answer (score 2):

For any pointer or array `p` and index `i` the expression `p[i]` and `*(p + i)` are the same.

Now if the index is `0` then we have `p[0]` which is the same as `*(p + 0)`, and `*(p + 0)` is the same as `*(p)` which is the same as `*p`.

That is, if you have a pointer and dereference it, then you will get exactly what the pointer is pointing to, for example the first element in an array pointed to by the pointer.

If you want to set all elements in the array to zero, you have two choices: Either use an explicit loop and set each and every element to zero. Or since you have an array of integers you could use [`memset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memset) to set each and every *byte* in the array to zero.

Using [`memset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memset) you could do e.g.

```
memset(p_array, 0, sizeof(*p_array) * num_elements);
```